# How to check if there are equal number and then print the largest number

Tags: python, int, max

I have this exercise where I need to create a function that prints the largest number of three numbers and in case there are two  equal number it should return a message.

I did it:

```
def max_number(num1, num2, num3):
  if len(max(num1, num2, num3)) > 1:
    return "It's  a tie"
  return max(num1, num2, num3)
```

But as I found out **len** does not work with **int** and I also know that I could try all the possibilities out using **elif**, but that would be harder if I had more parameters. Is there any way I can solve it?

Thanks

Comment: The answers seem to make an assumption I want to check.  What output do you need for `(2, 2, 7)`?  The answers you're getting tend to assume that this is a "tie" case.

Comment: max(2,2,7) doesn't return a tie...

Comment: @Prune In that example the output I want is 7. The code should print "It's a tie" just when I have the largest  number equal to the other. For example, the code should print It is a tie when the numbers are  `(2, 7, 7)`. So the list comprehension works well in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use list comprehension, then `len` for the list:

```
def max_number(*nums):
  m = max(nums)
  if len([i for i in nums if i == m]) > 1:
    return "It's  a tie"
  return max(nums)
```

Comment: This wouldn't work would it? Say 7 is the max, at one point you compare the 7 with its self.

Comment: @AaronD.Rodriguez: what did this code do when you tried it?

Comment: @Prune That's a good question, i don't get why Aaron's try didn't work.

Comment: I must have typed something wrong the first time. It worked this time.

Comment: @AaronD.Rodriguez Yup, that was what i was expecting too, thanks for the up-vote :-)

Comment: You should probably store the `max`, because right now you are recomputing it every time.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the numbers to the `set` constructor and check if the set has a length of the number of numbers:

```
def max_number(*numbers):
    if len(set(numbers)) == len(numbers):
        return max(numbers)
    return "It's a tie"
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution:

```
def max_number(num1, num2, num3):
  m = max(num1, num2, num3)
  return m if [num1, num2, num3].count(m) == 1 else "It's  a tie"
```

Comment: Don't think this works. If the tie happens with the 2 smaller numbers the function returns a tie when there really is a max

Comment: @kerwei Thanks for letting me know. I reworked it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `heapq.nlargest` to get the largest two of the given numbers, and if they are equal, it's considered a tie:

```
from heapq import nlargest
from operator import eq

def max_number(*numbers):
    if eq(*nlargest(numbers, 2)):
        return "It's a tie"
    return max(numbers)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another method:

```
def max_number(num1, num2, num3):
    sorted_list = sorted([num1, num2, num3])
    if sorted_list[1] == sorted_list[2]:
        return "It's a tie"
    else:
        return sorted_list[2]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think it's interesting to point out that when you sort a list out the default is the ascending order, so it's important to pay attention to the index.

Comment: With default sorting, which is in ascending order, you can also do this ```sorted_list[-2] == sorted_list[-1]``` . It slices the list in reverse order and therefore, you do not have to keep track of the index

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `list.count` method to count the number of occurrences of the maximum value:

```
def max_number(*numbers):
    m = max(numbers)
    if numbers.count(m) > 1:
        return "It's a tie"
    return max(numbers)
```